# faucet (grohe arden?) leak. how do i remove the handle, get to the O ring

Tags: bathroom, leak, faucet

Got a 2 handle bathroom faucet that seems to be leaking. I think it is a Grohe Arden (I am not the original owner of the house and the faucet is over 10 yrs old). The only place I can see Grohe written is on the aerator. Anyway, I am trying to get the handle off and get to the O ring. How do I do that. I have attached an image of the faucet. A newbie to this kind of stuff.

[image: faucet]

[[image: removed handle]]
[[image: removed the nut. now, what to do?]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7gt8.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The little dome shaped item on the top of the handle is a cover. You can carefully pry it off and there will be a screw in there. Remove the screw and the handle will come off.

Comment: Ok, did that got to image 3 where there is lockpin sitting on top a nut. Removed the lockpin, Tried to unscrew the nut. didn't make much progress. What should I do? What is the hex nut at the base for?